# Are there any potential security risks in connecting to a Murmur (Mumble) server?

Tags: voip

I've created a free server on a website, but I'm a bit cautious on connecting to it. Are there any potential security risks in connecting to a Murmur (Mumble) server?

Comment: Only those that are within the client your using to connect to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any time you exchange data with software you incur a security risk.  For example a client could potentially connect o a malicious server that exploits a buffer overflow in the protocol to obtain arbitrary remote code execution on the client.  If this is a concerns you find  murmur client that wasn't written in C/C++.  Managed languages,  like python, and java,  still suffer from very serious security defects but less than that of C/C++.